# Module Specifier error when running simple script.js on Windows Powershell/cmd prompt

Tags: shell, command-line, command-line-interface, k6

After coming across k6, according to their documentation I created a simple Javascript file with the code given in their documentation, saved it. But when Im trying t run it, it is showing the below response.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMRmv.png)
How can I get rid of this, I know its something obvious but can anyone help with this?

I tried saving the file on another editor and running it again on command prompt but it showed the same.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask], and then [edit] your question to provide a [mre] as _text_ (not screenshots).

Comment: You forgot to show your file. But my money is on you trying to import `intro.js`, whereas you should import `./intro.js`.